# How can I convert Tweetinvi's args.json to object

Tags: c#, json, twitter, tweetinvi

I am using [Tweetinvi](https://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/) to get Twitter stream, quite easy/friendly to use but unable to parse Json to a Tweet. Can anybody help me converting/parsing args.Json to a Tweet (using Newtonsoft.json)?

```
filteredStream.JsonObjectReceived += (sender, args) =>
{
    var tweet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tweetinvi.Core.Interfaces.ITweet>(args.Json);
};
```

Above line ends up with following Error because ITweet is an interface:

```
Could not create an instance of type Tweetinvi.Core.Interfaces.ITweet. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated
```

Comment: the error message is clear. Instead of interface, use concrete class provided in the library if any, or try create a class that inherits `ITweet`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the method that is already implemented:

```
 fs.MatchingTweetReceived += (sender, args) => { var tweet = args.Tweet; };
```

If you really want to do the Json conversion on your own you can do the following:

```
 var jsonConvert = TweetinviContainer.Resolve<IJsonObjectConverter>();
 var tweetDTO = jsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ITweetDTO>(json);
 var tweet = Tweet.GenerateTweetFromDTO(tweetDTO);
```